# Floating point exception c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do some c++ programming and the following line gives me a "Floating point exception" at runtime:

```
realAnswer=(0-720+5*1440)/((775-720)/(750-720))+720;
```

What could be causing the problem? (realAnswer is a double)

Edit: added the slash

Comment: works pretty fine for me

Comment: I found the problem, it was a line before this one that made it fail Thanks for everyones suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the missing * that Petar has pointed out, your calculation uses only integers while you wish to get a double. The answer you are getting now is rounded down (723).

The following will get you the double precision I assume you are looking for. I have tested this by compiling and running it:

```
realAnswer=(0.0-720.0+5.0*1440.0)/((775.0-720.0)*(750.0-720.0))+720.0;
```

This gives 723.927 as a result.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a *:

```
realAnswer=(0-720+5*1440)/((775-720)*(750-720))+720;
```

Comment: well, I don't, but usually the * is omitted when you hand write equations

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, Presumably it would be, considering that's what it would be in math. Maybe it was a typo instead.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it was supposed to be a / and I already have one in my code